# Принимает ли Play Market приложения WebView?

Tags: android, google-play

Подскажите:

1.Принимает ли Play Market приложения WebView?

2.Принимает ли Play Market приложения WebView, сделанные не через Android Studio, а через сторонние сервисы наподобие — [AppsGeyser](http://www.appsgeyser.com)?

3.Стоит ли вообще делать WebView приложения с помощью различных сервисов? И какие плюсы и минусы таких сервисов?

Comment: Что такое "приложение WebView"?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, все зависит от ваших потребностей и возможностей. Несомненным плюсом webView является возможность использования кода для android и ios одновременно, но это "преимуществу" давно есть у конкурентов.

Сейчас выбор стал шире, например, появился Flutter - он позволяет вести 1 проект для ios И android. Этот фреймворк от гугл, язык dart (помесь js и java). На мой взгляд не очень удобная вещь, сыроватая, но это только мое мнение.

Очень популярен reactnative, они позицианируют себя как отдельная либа, т.е. НЕ WebView приложение. Основной язык кажется js (один проект на android и ios). Многие крупные компании его используют, например Тесла.

Почему я избегаю советовать вам разработку именно WebView приложения? Все просто - это лишний слой. View часть вашего приложения будет на html и css. Рано или поздно проиойдет перекос архитектуры и вы начнете слать ajax-запросы из Html, но при этом продолжите работать с базой и ядром через фремворк. Если вам нужно именно это, посмотрите в сторону Cordova.

Если вам нужен один android проект, то мб проще написать его на котлине, не ввязываясь в кросплатформенность? Уверяю, что проблем и задач так или иначе хватит.

**Дополнение:**

Ах да, на счет Play Market. Play Market принимает практически все. Он задает тренд и основы. Никто не станет делать фреймворк/бибилиотеку без базовой поддержки play market. Так что об этом можете не беспокоиться. Возможно будут какие-то особенности, но их решить не сложно.

Comment: Как насчёт сторонних сервисов создания WebView?

Comment: почитайте отзывы, лично я такими сервисами никогда не интересовался